# Deny access to a webpage using web.config

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, forms-authentication

I have searched Google & SO posts, but could not get any results that solved my issue.

My web.config is:

```
<location path="~/reports/PayPeriodQtrReport.aspx, ~/reports/PayPeriodDetailReport.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="PayrollReports"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="~/reports/ManifestAnnualReport.aspx, ~/reports/ManifestDetailedReport.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="ManifestReports"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The authorization works as required (meaning a person with "PayrollReports" role, is not able to see the Manifest Reports in the menu item and a person with "ManifestReports" role is not able to see the Payroll Reports in the menu item).

**Problem:**
As a user with "PayrollReports" role, I can type into my url 
 `http:\\mysite.com\reports\ManifestDetailedReport.aspx` and the page shows up. What should be displayed is unauthorizedaccess.aspx

Similarly, as a user with "ManifestReports" role, I can type into my url `http:\\mysite.com\reports\PayPeriodQtrReport.aspx` and the page shows up. What should be displayed is unauthorizedaccess.aspx

**Question:**
Using web.config, how can I prevent a user from hacking into the page by typing in the url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put each file in it's own `location` entry and remove the `~/`:

```
<location path="reports/PayPeriodQtrReport.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="PayrollReports"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

etc...

This assumes you are using a RoleProvider. Either you are using the built-in RoleProvider or you a custom RoleProvider that inherits from `RoleProvider` and is properly specified in your web.config.

Comment: Are you using a proper RoleProvider? How do you determine who is in what role?

Comment: Who is in what role is defined in the "Web Site Administration Tool". How would I determine if the app is using a RoleProvider (application was written by another developer) ?

Comment: Is `roleManager` specified / enabled in your web.config? What is it?

Comment: my bad. RoleManager is defined, in the application root web.config. The web.config that I am working with, is in a reports folder.

Comment: If you are already in the `reports` folder, then path will be `path="PayPeriodQtrReport.aspx"`. The path in the answer was for if you are in root web.config.